# List the ProductCode, ProductName, and number of orders for the product with the most orders.Count of orders as “OrderCount

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I could not be able to get the max count
these are the two codes that I tried to use

```
select o.productCode, p.productname, count(*) as ordercount
from orderdetails o, products p
where o.productCode= p.productCode
and max(ordecount)
group by productcode

select o.productCode, p.productname, count(*) as ordercount
from orderdetails o, products p
where o.productCode= p.productCode
in ( 
      select max(count(*) )
      from orderdetails o, products p
      where o.productCode= p.productCode
)
```

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output data

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.productCode, 
       ANY_VALUE(p.productname), -- needed for to aviod not full group by error
       count(*) as ordercount
from orderdetails o, products p
where o.productCode= p.productCode
group by productcode
ORDER BY ordercount DESC LIMIT 1 -- select the only record with maximal value
```

If there exists more than one productCode with the same maximal orders amount only one of them (random in shown query) will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your answer, you can just sort your resultset and keep the first row only:

```
select o.productCode, p.productname, count(*) as ordercount
from orderdetails o
inner join products p on o.productCode= p.productCode
group by o.productCode, p.productname
order by ordercount desc 
limit 1
```

Note that I modified your query to use standard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword), rather than old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause), whose syntax is much harder to follow and that have fallen out of favor since ANSI SQL 92 was released (decades ago).